How to safely use a 110 VAC Solenoid Valve in a water system?
I am using 110 VAC solenoid valves linked here, to control the water flow in my system.
https://www.electricsolenoidvalves.com/1-8-110-120-volts-ac-electric-brass-solenoid-valve/?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw4ri0BhAvEiwA8oo6F37ZO-QkrQOIDJudoT-lEpTf20DWzGAsCZ2aUyxYFOBWDRZJsGFxJRoC0sMQAvD_BwE#description
I want to make sure that the system has safety measures. I am using solid-state relays between the solenoid valves and my microcontroller to have them act as a switch. At the moment I realize the only way to power the valves is to connect them to the wall outlet. Is this the only way to power them? The valves will be open for a good amount of time (10<) so overheating is also a concern. They require 10 watts or .5 amps to actuate. What is the safest way to design the circuit to prevent short circuits or risks? And how would I ground the valves themselves for safety as this will be used in a water system?
Also are there any tips on how to extend the wires on the valves? I was thinking about crimping the wires.



What risks are you trying to mitigate? Step one to risk reduction is to establish a list of risks. Short circuit is one. From where to where?

You will definitely want to earth ground the pipe right at the valve.

If safety is your main concern and it well should be your best bet is to stop considering 110/120 VAC actuated valves and look for ones that use 24VAC. Common lawn and garden sprinkler valves use this low voltage.
The same company you linked in your question has 24VAC valves listed at the site with the same looking body style and piping connections.

That is unfortunately not an option at the moment as I already have 110 VAC valves, but it is definitely something I will keep in mind in the future.
-Thank you

@NahiyanMuhammad I would suggest exchanging the 110VAC valve with the 24V version - based on your apparent experience, it's best to not mix 110VAC and water as you likely will have safety risks that you are not considering.

@Searo - Saying it is not an option is not really correct. Your trying to find a bandaid solution for when you purchased the wrong valves should be addressed the correct way - either return the valves (or eat your pride) and get the correct 24VAC valves.

@MichaelKaras Upon receiving your feedback, I have used the 110 V AC Valve. You will be happy to know that the circuit functions great, I have incorporated a transient suppressor using an RC network to protect against voltage spikes, added a 2 Amp circuit breaker for system safety,  and grounded the whole system from the valve to the power output. It amazes me, growing up I learned that engineers were meant to do the impossible and test themselves. Clearly, that is not the case with the older generation.
